# Add/subtract variables in a really dumb shell

Tags: shell, math, busybox, dash-shell

I am writing a shell script which works on my local `/bin/sh` fine (dash on Ubuntu 13.04), but I unltimately need to run it on a dumb box where I'm getting an error because of an operation on variables:

```
$((n2 - n1 + 1))
```

doesn't work, I get an error like:

```
syntax error: you disabled math support for $((arith)) syntax
```

I don't know a lot about the `sh` on there but I think this thing is busybox.  How can I do maths on this dumb shell?

---

***edit*** with list of applets

```
~ # busybox --list
[
arp
ash
cat
chgrp
chmod
chown
chroot
chvt
clear
cmp
cp
cut
date
dd
deallocvt
df
dmesg
du
echo
env
false
find
freeramdisk
ftpget
ftpput
grep
gunzip
gzip
hexdump
hwclock
ifconfig
ln
losetup
ls
md5sum
mkdir
mkfifo
mknod
mkswap
more
mount
mv
nslookup
ping
ping6
ps
pwd
renice
reset
rm
rmdir
route
seq
sh
sha1sum
sha256sum
sleep
sort
swapoff
swapon
switch_root
sync
tar
taskset
tee
telnet
test
tftp
time
top
touch
true
umount
uname
uniq
uptime
usleep
vconfig
vi
wget
whoami
yes
```

Comment: Yes, it's busybox. Since your `ash` is so stripped down, I guess your `busybox` doesn't have the `awk` applet either? Or an external `bc`?

Comment: No results with `find / -name awk` or `find / -name bc`

Comment: `expr` maybe? You might also want to check `$ busybox awk` and `$ busybox expr` in case there are just no symlinks.

Comment: Yeah I already tried ``expr`` too, no good ...

Comment: Then you're pretty much stuck. Is it an option to replace the busybox with one that has maths support compiled in (guess not, otherwise you wouldn't ask)?

Comment: Maybe on one dev box ... but probably not on 500,000+ boxes out in the wild  ;)

Comment: Where does your busybox binary come from. Several tricks *might* be possible but depend on some busybox applet or other, so knowing the exact configuration of your binary will help a lot. It will give people something to toy around with. If no link can be provided, `busybox --list` will at least give the list of available applets.

Comment: yes - finally someone asked for a list of applets...

Comment: Does your `uniq` have `-u`? Then I have a new solution for you in the waiting.

Comment: Yes, `-u` option works!

Comment: @wim Didn't get a notification for your comment, so sorry for the late reply. I posted the solution which should finally work for you based on the applets you have available :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another specific solution to your problem (`n2 - n1 + 1`) based on `seq`, `sort -nr` and `uniq -u` (POSIX-compliant).

```
foo()
{
    {
        seq 1 "$2"
        seq 0 "$1"
    } \
        | sort -n \
        | uniq -u \
        | grep -n "" \
        | sort -nr \
        | { read num; echo "${num%:*}"; }
}

$ foo 100 2000
1901
```

Comment: This one works.  I'm very impressed with the amount of time and effort you've put into this silly little problem, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

### Generic addition/subtraction/multiplication/division with `seq`+`grep`+`sort`

Notes:

- All of these are POSIX-compliant, but there is a slightly faster non-POSIX `subtract_nonposix` which relies on a `grep` supporting `-w` and `-B` (non-POSIX, but even `busybox`' `grep` supports them)
- `add`/`subtract` support only unsigned integers as input
- `multiply`/`divide` support signed integers as input
- `subtract`/`multiply`/`divide` can deal with negative results
- depending on the input `multiply`/`divide` might be very costly (see comments)
- `subtract`/`multiply` may pollute your namespace (they use `$__x` and `$__y` respectively) if not used in a subshell

`arith.sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh

is_uint()
{
    case "$1" in
        ''|*[!0-9]*) return 1
                     ;;
    esac
    [ "$1" -ge 0 ]
}

is_int()
{
    case "${1#-}" in
        ''|*[!0-9]*) return 1
                     ;;
    esac
}

# requires seq, grep -n, sort -nr
# reasonably fast
add()
{
    if   ! is_uint "$1" \
      || ! is_uint "$2"; then
        echo "Usage: add <uint1> <uint2>"
        return 1
    fi
    [ "$1" -eq 0 ] && { echo "$2"; return; }
    [ "$2" -eq 0 ] && { echo "$1"; return; }

    {
        seq 1 "$1"
        seq 1 "$2"
    } \
        | grep -n "" \
        | sort -nr \
        | { read num; echo "${num%[-:]*}"; }
}

# requires seq, grep -n, sort -nr, uniq -u
# reasonably fast
subtract()
{
    if   ! is_uint "$1" \
      || ! is_uint "$2"; then
        echo "Usage: subtract <uint1> <uint2>"
        return 1
    fi

    if [ "$1" -ge "$2" ]; then
        __x="$1"
        __y="$2"
    else
        __x="$2"
        __y="$1"
    fi

    {
        seq 0 "${__x}"
        seq 0 "${__y}"
    } \
        | sort -n \
        | uniq -u \
        | grep -n "" \
        | sort -nr \
        | \
        {
            read num
            : ${num:=0}
            [ "${__x}" = "$2" ] && [ "$1" -ne "$2" ] && minus='-'
            echo "${minus}${num%:*}"
        }
}

# requires seq, grep -wB
# faster than subtract(), but requires non-standard grep -wB
subtract_nonposix()
{
    if   ! is_uint "$1" \
      || ! is_uint "$2"; then
        echo "Usage: subtract <uint1> <uint2>"
        return 1
    fi

    if [ "$1" -ge "$2" ]; then
        __x="$1"
        __y="$2"
    else
        __x="$2"
        __y="$1"
    fi
    seq 0 "${__x}" \
        | grep -w -B "${__y}" "${__x}" \
        | \
        {
            read num
            [ "${__x}" = "$2" ] && [ "$1" -ne "$2" ] && minus='-'
            echo "${minus}${num}"
        }
}

# requires seq, sort -nr, add()
# very slow if multiplicand or multiplier is large
multiply()
{
    if   ! is_int "$1" \
      || ! is_int "$2"; then
        echo "Usage: multiply <int1> <int2>"
        return 1
    fi
    [ "$2" -eq 0 ] && { echo 0; return; }
    # make sure to use the smaller number for the outer loop
    # to speed up things a little if possible
    if [ $1 -ge $2 ]; then
        __x="$1"
        __y="$2"
    else
        __x="$2"
        __y="$1"
    fi
    __x="${__x#-}"
    __y="${__y#-}"

    seq 1 "${__y}" \
        | while read num; do
            sum="$(add "${sum:-0}" "${__x}")"
            echo "${sum}"
        done \
        | sort -nr \
        | \
        {
            read num
            if   [ "$1" -lt 0 -a "$2" -gt 0 ] \
              || [ "$2" -lt 0 -a "$1" -gt 0 ]; then
                minus='-'
            fi
            echo "${minus}${num}"
        }
}

# requires subtract()
# very costly if dividend is large and divisor is small
divide()
{
    if   ! is_int "$1" \
      || ! is_int "$2"; then
        echo "Usage: divide <int1> <int2>"
        return 1
    fi
    [ "$2" -eq 0 ] && { echo "division by zero"; return 1; }

    (
        sum="${1#-}"
        y="${2#-}"
        count=
        while [ "${sum}" -ge "${y}" ]; do
            sum="$(subtract "${sum}" "${y}")"
            # no need to use add() for a simple +1 counter,
            # this is way faster
            count="${count}."
        done

        if   [ "$1" -lt 0 -a "$2" -gt 0 ] \
          || [ "$2" -lt 0 -a "$1" -gt 0 ]; then
            minus='-'
        fi
        echo "${minus}${#count}"
    )
}

echo "10 4 14
4 10
10 10
2 -2
-2 -2
0 0
x y" | while read x y; do
    for op in add subtract subtract_nonposix multiply divide; do
        printf -- "${x} ${y} %-17s = %s\n" "${op}" "$("${op}" "${x}" "${y}")"
    done
    echo
done
```

Example run:

```
$ ./arith.sh
10 4 add               = 14
10 4 subtract          = 6
10 4 subtract_nonposix = 6
10 4 multiply          = 40
10 4 divide            = 2

4 10 add               = 14
4 10 subtract          = -6
4 10 subtract_nonposix = -6
4 10 multiply          = 40
4 10 divide            = 0

10 10 add               = 20
10 10 subtract          = 0
10 10 subtract_nonposix = 0
10 10 multiply          = 100
10 10 divide            = 1

2 -2 add               = Usage: add <uint1> <uint2>
2 -2 subtract          = Usage: subtract <uint1> <uint2>
2 -2 subtract_nonposix = Usage: subtract <uint1> <uint2>
2 -2 multiply          = -4
2 -2 divide            = -1

-2 -2 add               = Usage: add <uint1> <uint2>
-2 -2 subtract          = Usage: subtract <uint1> <uint2>
-2 -2 subtract_nonposix = Usage: subtract <uint1> <uint2>
-2 -2 multiply          = 4
-2 -2 divide            = 1

0 0 add               = 0
0 0 subtract          = 0
0 0 subtract_nonposix = 0
0 0 multiply          = 0
0 0 divide            = division by zero

x y add               = Usage: add <uint1> <uint2>
x y subtract          = Usage: subtract <uint1> <uint2>
x y subtract_nonposix = Usage: subtract <uint1> <uint2>
x y multiply          = Usage: multiply <int1> <int2>
x y divide            = Usage: divide <int1> <int2>
```

Comment: Favoriting this one. Maybe onetime will understand how it works. ;)

Comment: @jm666 I was hoping my attempt at an explanation was good enough ;-) which part don't you understand?

Comment: @jm666 Well, my code makes understanding Chinese seem easier than basic arithmetics, but I promise it's actually supereasy ;-) I will dissect the pipe and add the intermediate output tomorrow as part of the explanation.

Comment: I must have a crippled version of grep, because -B is invalid option

Comment: Finally posted a solution which does not need `grep -B`, improved the generic functions and gave them their own post as well as split the original specific solution which was part of this answer for the sake of readbility.

Answer (score 3):

## head, tail and wc

If your busybox has `head`, `tail` and `wc` built in, you might try the following:

```sh
head -c $n2 /dev/zero | tail -c +$n1 | wc -c
```

The first will generate a sequence of `n2` zero bytes. The second will start at position `n1`, counting from 1, so it will skip `n1 - 1` bytes. Therefore the resulting sequence has `n2 - n1 + 1` bytes. This count can be computed using `wc -c`.

## head, tail and ls or stat

Tried this with my busybox, although its configuration might differ from yours. I'm not sure whether `wc` will be that more likely than `expr`. If you have `head` and `tail` but no `wc`, then you could probably write the result to a temporary file, and then use `stat` or `ls` to obtain the size as a string. Examples for this are included below.

## seq and wc

If you have `wc` but not `head` and `tail`, then you could substitute `seq` instead:

```sh
seq $n1 $n2 | wc -l
```

## seq, tr and stat

As your comment indicates you have no `wc` but do have `seq`, here is an alternative provided you have sufficuently complete `ls` and also `tr`, perhaps even `stat`. Alas, I just noticed that `tr` isn't in your list of applets either. Nevertheless, for future reference, here it is:

```sh
seq $n1 $n2 | tr -d [0-9] > tempfilename
stat -c%s tempfilename
```

This creates a sequence of `n2 - n1 + 1` lines, then removes all digits, leaving only that many newlines, which it writes to a file. We then print its size.

## dd and ls

But as you don't have `tr`, you'll need something different. `dd` might suite your needs, since you can use it a bit like `head` or `tail`.

```sh
dd if=/dev/zero of=tmp1 bs=1 count=$n2 #   n2
dd if=tmp1 of=tmp2 bs=1 skip=$n1       # - n1
echo >> tmp2                           # +  1
set -- dummy `ls -l tmp2`
echo $6
rm tmp1 tmp2
```

This creates a sequence of `n2` null bytes, then skips the first `n1` of it. It appends a single newline to add 1 to its size. Then it uses `ls` to print the size of that file, and sets the positional variables `$1`, `$2`, … based on its output. `$6` should be the column containing the size. Unless I missed something, this should all be available to you.

## Alternative to busybox

If everything else fails, you might still implement your own digit-wise subtraction algorithm, using a lot of case distinctions. But that would require a lot of work, so you might be better of shipping a statically linked `expr` binary, or something specifically designed for your use case, instead of a scripted approach.

Comment: This looks fun.. but unfortunately, I don't have head tail _or_ wc!  :)   `seq` was something I forgot about and I was actually able to use that for something else I needed though !

Comment: @wim: The above suggestion using `dd` should work for you, I think.

Comment: I think you partly mixed `n2` and `n1` in your answers (`n2 - n1` vs `n1 - n2`). Other than that, those are very neat even though they won't work if the subtracting number is greater than the other, which I hope wim does not require :-) Care to elaborate on the `dummy` in your `dd` approach?

Comment: @AdrianFrühwirth: I noticed that `configure` scripts created by autoconf will use that `dummy`idiom a lot, and I'm not sure what the intention is. Might be only neccessary for cases where the called program returns no words at all, but until I'm sure I decided to simply copy that idiom as is. And you are right, I mixed variable order in several places, will try to fix them consistently.

Comment: @MvG you can use `dd if=/dev/zero bs=1 count=$n >>$memory_file` so is possible adding into existing memory_file with dd (for the consistency, instead of the echo) :). So, is possible make small shell scripts like fc_add m1 100, fc_sub m1 10, fc_add m1 40, fc_show m1 :) :) Congratz: REALLY CREATIVE IDEA.

Comment: @MvG Thanks for the clarification! This would seem logical and is probably the reason, although it is unnecessary since [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/set.html) states that *"The command 'set --' without argument shall unset all positional parameters and set the special parameter '#' to zero."* (as opposed to printing the list of vars like without any arguments). Maybe this used to be unspecified earlier or some crappy shells ignore(d) the standard and `autoconf` is just being nice to them.

Answer (score 2):

Really weird idea - usable only if you have network connection:

```
a=2,3
b=2.7
res=`wget -q -O - "http://someyourserver:6000/($a+$b)*5/2"`
echo $res
```

so you can do calculations over the network. You must setup one simple web server will get the PATH_INFO from the request and return only the result.

the server part (very simplified - without any error handling etc.) can be like next `app.psgi`:

```
my $app = sub {
    my $env = shift;
    my $calc = $env->{PATH_INFO};
    $calc =~ s:^/::; #remove 1.st slash
    $calc =~ s:[^\d\(\)\+\*/\-\.\,]::g; #cleanup, only digits and +-*/()., allowed
    $calc =~ s/,/\./g; #change , to .
    my $res = eval $calc;
        return [ 200, ['Content-Type' => 'text/plain'], [ "$res" ] ];
};
```

run with `plackup -p 6000 app.psgi`

or can use any other simple CGI or php script.

Comment: I had the same basic idea but it seemed so crazy and kludgy that I did not dare to actually post it. I am pretty certain it won't help the OP in his scenario but maybe someone else later might find this helpful, so +1.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, if you can reconfigure and rebuild BusyBox and enable "bash-compatible extensions", which should give you the ability to do mathematics. You will have to cross-compile your BusyBox again and replace the old binaries with your new one on your target (assuming you have the environment to do so). The BusyBox executable is only one binary, so you will only need to deal with simple replacement of one file.

I have BusyBox 1.19.4 and the mathematics evaluation works just fine.

Comment: According to his comment recompiling busybox is not an option though.

Answer (score 1):

### Add/Subtract numbers using only `printf`

For me, the previous answers didn't work since I don't have `seq`, nor `grep`, nor `wc`, `head` or `tail`, not even `dd`.
My bash syntax doesn't support the math syntax $((n1+n2)), and not even the range syntax {1..N}. so it definitely was a tough environment.

I did manage to have basic add/subtract operations with small numbers (up to few thousands) using the following technique (calculate n1-n2):

```
n1=100
n2=20
str_n1=`printf "%${n1}s"` # "prints" 100 spaces, and store in str_n1
str_n2=`printf "%${n2}s"` # "prints" 20 spaces, and store in str_n2

if [ n1 -gt n2 ]    # if the n1 > n2, then:
then
    str_sub=${str_n1%$str_n2}   #delete str_n2 from str_n1
else
    str_sub=${str_n2%$str_n1}   #delete str_n1 from str_n2
fi

# until now we created a string with 100 spaces, then a second string with 20 spaces, then we deleted the 20 of 2nd string from 1st string, so now all we left is to:

sub_result=${#str_sub}   #check the length of str_sub
```

Same technique can be used also for adding numbers (continue from last example):

```
str_add=$str_n1$str_n2  # concat the two string to have 120 spaces together
add_result=${#str_add}  # check the length of add_result
```

Now, in my case, I had to work with bigger numbers (up to ten of millions), and it cannot work with this method like that since it actually needs to print millions of spaces, and it takes forever.
Instead, since I don't need to whole number, but just a part of it, i took the middle of the number using the substring syntax:

```
n1=10058000
n2=10010000

n1=${n1:3:3}  # -> 580 (takes 3 chars from the 3rd char)
n2=${n2:3:3}  # -> 100
```

Then calculate what I need with smaller numbers (of course needs to take more parameters in consideration for cases like n1=10158000, and n2=10092000)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the original solution I posted to your problem (`n2 - n1 + 1`) based on `seq` and `grep`.

```
foo()
{
  seq 0 "$2" \
    | grep -nw -B "$1" "$2" \
    | { read num; echo "${num%[-:]*}"; }
}

$ foo 100 2000
1901
```

How it works:

- First we generate a sequence of numbers from `0` to `n2`
- Then we `grep` for `n2` and include the leading `n1` lines in the output. The first line holds our result now. We add the line number so the zero-based sequence accounts for the `+1` (the line numbers and actual numbers will be off-by-one)
- Then we fetch the first line with `read` (basically emulating `head -n 1`) and
- discard the actual number from the output - the line number is the proper result